# how can i select double field where different clause

Tags: mysql, sql

can I use a query like this:

```
SELECT a AS x, a AS y 
FROM table
WHERE x='1' and y='2'
```

how can I use such as that query...

Comment: how can `x` be 1 AND `y` 2 when `x` is `y`, as `x` is `a` and `a` is `y`... you will never get any hits.

Comment: Can you explain? the title mention selecting double fields. Is the problem the aliases you use, x and y? is the problem the AND condition? do you want to use OR condition? or IN ? is it a typo that `a` is `x` and also `y` at same time? please explain...

Answer (score 2):

You have to **take main query in temp** as follow:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT a AS x, a AS y 
FROM table) as temp WHERE temp.x = '1' AND temp.y = '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot use column aliases defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause.  This is true in all databases, not only MySQL.  One method is to use a subquery (or CTE in databases that support them).

MySQL also extends the `HAVING` clause.  This allows you to do:

```
SELECT a AS x, a AS y 
FROM table
HAVING x ='1' and y = '2';
```

I assume that this question is made up, because the query can never return any rows.